# FreeBSD perform certain task when a new user is created

Tags: samba, freebsd, rc.d

Is there a way to perform additional tasks every time a new user is created with [adduser(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=adduser&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) in FreeBSD?

To be more precise, i'd like to create a directory for every new user and map this user with [pdbedit(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pdbedit&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) to the SAM database.

Some Linux distributions like [debian/ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/de/man8/adduser.8.html) provide a handy way to solve this problem. If a script called `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` exists, it'll be executed after a new user has been created:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /srv/samba/$1
chown $1:$2 /srv/samba/$1
chmod 775 /srv/samba/$1
```

How would I do this using FreeBSD?

Comment: Having glanced through the source, the simple answer is probably no. But since adduser(8) is a shell script, you could easily extend it. Alternatively, use your bash script to make a call to adduser(8) or pw(8) first.

Comment: Another way is to write a daemon that would use `kevent` syscall to monitor changes to `/etc/passwd` file and react on them.

Comment: On Unix systems, they are "directories" and not the Windows-ism of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed [Richard Smiths](https://serverfault.com/questions/1017641/freebsd-perform-certain-task-when-a-new-user-is-created#comment1321352_1017641) suggestion and solved my problem with a very simple shell script, which calls [adduser(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?adduser(8)) as well as [pdbedit(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pdbedit&sektion=8&n=1) and creates the corresponding directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

user=$1

# create user and add to SAM database
adduser $user
pdbedit -a $user

# create private samba directory
mkdir /srv/samba/$user
chown $user:$user /srv/samba/$user
chmod 775 /srv/samba/$user
```